# how to put the text in the box

Tags: boxes

I want to put a long text in the box using LaTeX, thus, would someone tell me how to put the text in the box? Using `\makebox?` however, it doesn't work, I use `\makebox[10cm]{text in the box}`, there is no box in the file.

Comment: `\fbox{\makebox[10cm]{text in the box}}`

Comment: @sweetyBaby As Herbert's comment indicates, perhaps you are confusing 'typesetting in a box' with 'surrounding by a frame'. `\makebox` certainly typesets material in a box: perhaps you might clarify.

Comment: thanks, however, there is still some problem, please refer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67538/how-to-use-makebox-in-latex

Answer (score 5):

You can use `\framebox` instead of `\makebox` (which is almost the same as the suggestion in the comments of using `\fbox` around `\makebox`). `\fbox` is a simplified version of`\framebox` in the same way that `\mbox` is a simplified version of `\makebox` for the common case in which you just want the natural size of the contents so do not need to specify any lengths.