# How to use makebox in LaTeX

Tags: formatting, boxes

I try to use `\makebox` around the word, however, all text in the same line, why? Here is my code, would someone help me?

```
\fbox{\makebox[10cm]{$(t_{SS}{+}t_{MS}{\leq}t_{FS}){\land}(t_{FS}{\leq}t_{BS}){\land}(t_{SS}{+}t_{MS}{+}t_{FS}{+}t_{BS}{\leq}3)$\\

$(t_{SS}{+}t_{MS}{\leq}t_{BS}){\land}(t_{BS}{\leq}t_{FS}){\land}(t_{SS}{+}t_{MS}{+}t_{FS}{+} t_{BS}{\leq}3)$\\
}
```

Comment: For more on boxes (and (La)TeX's interpretation of them), I recommend that you read Section 6.6 of l2short.  You can get it online at http://texdoc.net/pkg/lshort or you'll probably have a copy on your computer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

normal boxes cannot have a linebreak, use

```
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{10cm}$(t_{SS}{+}t_{MS}{\leq}t_{FS}){\land}(t_{FS}{\leq}t_{BS}){\land}(t_{SS}{+}t_{MS}{+}t_{FS}{+}t_{BS}{\leq}3)$\\

$(t_{SS}{+}t_{MS}{\leq}t_{BS}){\land}(t_{BS}{\leq}t_{FS}){\land}(t_{SS}{+}t_{MS}{+}t_{FS}{+} t_{BS}{\leq}3)$\\
\end{minipage}}
```

or `\fbox{\parbox{10cm}{...}}`